# Adding to a scoreboard on canvas platform

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something a bit different, instead of putting the scoreboard outside of the Canvas, its inside it and associated with the canvas properties.

It's fully functional but I don't understand why it does not add to the score whenever a row is cleared.

Here's that part:

```
var totalPoints = 0;

function erase() {
    for ( var y = rows - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        var full = true;
        for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            if (board[y][x] == 0) {
                full = false;
                totalPoints--;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (full) {
            totalPoints++;
            for ( var j = y; j > 0; j--) {
                for ( var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                    board[j][x] = board[j-1][x]
                }
            }
            ++y; 
        }
    }
}

function showOnload(){
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillText("scores", 200, 100);
    c.fillText(totalPoints, 200, 140);
}
```

Note:

I've the `showOnload` function as a body `onload` for my `HTML` page, does this have anything to do with why it doesn't change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update score each time it is changed.

```
var totalPoints = 0;

function erase() {
    for ( var y = rows - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        var full = true;
        for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
            if (board[y][x] == 0) {
                full = false;
                totalPoints--;
                showOnload();                //HERE
                break;
            }
        }
        if (full) {
            totalPoints++;
            showOnload();                    //HERE
            for ( var j = y; j > 0; j--) {
                for ( var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                    board[j][x] = board[j-1][x]
                }
            }
            ++y; 
        }
    }
}

function showOnload(){
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillText("scores", 200, 100);
    c.fillText(totalPoints, 200, 140);
}
```

Comment: my god you found that so quickly... been on it for 2 hours now lol. So why wasn't it changing the values of totalPoints, even though i declared it globally. Shouldn't it change the value of totalPoints onLoad as well. Or am i miss understanding the meaning of global variables. 
Ah, newer problem now.. the numbers are stacking up on the Canvas.

Comment: It was changing the value of the global variable `totalPoints`, but it was not updating it on the `canvas` as the `showOnload()` method is called only when the `body` is loaded for the first time. With the updated code, the canvas is getting updated every time the points are changed.

Comment: But now that I've declared it onload on the body, the value of total points beforehand will exist on the canvas, meanwhile the updated code will keep adding on top of the other. Would you say its not a good idea to use onload for this?

Comment: If you are worrying about the score getting overwritten on the previous score making it difficult to read then, you can write `c.fillText("          ", 200, 140);` before `c.fillText(totalPoints, 200, 140);`, which will clear the previous score.

Comment: That doesn't work hmm. Maybe I should reconsider using the body onload.